# PHP opening tags question

Tags: php, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are PHP short tags acceptable to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use)

I saw some people use

```
<?=
```

instead of

```
<?php echo
```

It does make all those

```
<td something><?php echo $result;?></td>
<td something><?php echo $result2;?></td>
```

shorter and easy to read (to me at least) but my question is: is it desirable to use this syntax? Or is it deprecated/discouraged/simply wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supposedly, some people have short tags disabled on their server, so this won't work.

It's best practice to use `<?php echo $var; ?>` instead, but some will argue that it's more readable to use short tags and that having them disabled is rare.

For best results, avoid them.

**EDIT**: Apparently PHP 5.4 will allow you to use `<?=` syntax regardless of server configuration (I was not aware). In that case, I still say - avoid it if you care about portability and different environments that may not be running 5.4, or may have short tags disabled.

Comment: PHP 5.4 makes `<?= ?>` work even if short tags are turned off.

Comment: +1.  I would amend this to be "For best results *in any environment*, avoid them."  However, if you can guarantee that your application is running on a controlled environment, then I would say use the short tags, as they are easier to read.

Comment: PHP 5.4 does not have short tags always on. Only <?= works with short tags off now.

Comment: @cweiske: Is there difference? Please enlighten me, I am stuck on 5.2 still.

Comment: "short open tags" break `<?xml` declarations. You don't want them.

Comment: @cweiske: I'm not sure what you're trying to tell me. I never suggested using short tags, and your two comments seem to be disconnected. Can you clarify?

Comment: Yes, there is a difference. Always having short open tags activated - that is `<?` - will mean that you can't simply include files with XML header declarations in your PHP code, because the XML will be interpreted as PHP with short open tags. Having `<?=` always enabled breaks nothing, which is why it will be always on from 5.4 on.

Comment: Aha I see, I didn't actually realize that `<?` was considered a "short tag", I thought it only had to do with using `<?=`. Thanks a lot for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

`<? ?>` for PHP blocks is deprecated, but the PHP manual [says `<?= ?>` is going to stick around](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) (and from PHP 5.4 upwards, it'll be on always, even if short tags are off/removed). So, not deprecated, and common practice.

Comment: Interesting note about 5.4, maybe short tags will be back in style some day! There were rumors about them being removed in PHP6 but those have all proven to be false.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be deprecated because sometimes ago it was available only with switched on short tags, but will be available *always* since PHP 5.4

As of me, `<?=` is more readable, but you (or your team) should choose your own style

Answer (score 0):

`<?=` is known as short tags, PHP framework like CI support this and you can even add support for these in your php.ini files. That said, you should not use this tag at all. This is not so commonly encouraged and now a standard PHP tag with 5.4, using non standard tgas reduces the portability of your scripts. Time to correct my self, this is standard tag, I was stuck with 5.3 :(

Comment: This is a standard PHP tag. http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: @ceejayoz, thanks for correcting, though I will discourage using short tags till the time I see 5.4 everywhere.